# Unclosed XML Token

Tags: python, xml

How would I handle this error in Python 2.6?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fetch_xml_collect.py", line 32, in <module>
    tree=ET.parse(response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
    self._root = parser.close()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1254, in close
    self._parser.Parse("", 1) # end of data
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unclosed token: line 56, column 1
```

Current code being implemented:

```
while urlget==1:
        try:
                response = urllib.urlopen(rep)
        except IOError:
                print("reason")
        else:
                try:
                        tree=ET.parse(response)
                except IOError:
                        print("XML Parse Error\n")
                else:
                        root=tree.getroot()
                        print root[0].text
                        powerlist=tree.findall('meter/power')
                        print powerlist[0].tag,powerlist[0].text
```

The question is: How would I handle the above error in the given code?

Comment: try parsing it with `lxml.html`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
try:
   #Some code
   ...
except xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError, ex:
   print ex
   continue
```

Something like the above should work. Just `continue` if you get that error. It will continue with the next iteration with the loop, or if it's the last iteration, break out of the loop.

The XML is formed incorrectly, and is unable to be processed. Just skip it and go on to the next one.

Comment: thans for your help. sure. I wanna do it.I just regisiter the account. not enough reputation.